# Implementing BootstrapNotifier on Activity instead of Application class

Tags: android, altbeacon, beacon, eddystone

I am using altBeacon library for beacon detection. After checking out the sample codes on Beacon detection, they always implement the Interface `BootstrapNotifier` on the `Application` class instead of `Activity`, which is used for detecting beacons in the background. However I have noticed that beacon detection in the background stops when `BootstrapNotifier` is implemented on `Activity`. I don't want my app to detect beacons as soon as it is launched hence I have not implemented `BootStrapNotifier` on `Application` class.I have a specific requirement where I want beacons to be detected only after a particular `Activity` is launched and thereafter the beacons should always be detected in the background. Does the altBeacon library have any provisions for achieving this? Thanks.

[Sample code](https://altbeacon.github.io/android-beacon-library/samples.html)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it is possible to detect beacons in the background only after an `Activity` starts, but you still need to make a custom `Application` class that implements the `BootstrapNotifier`.

The reason this is necessary is because of the Android lifecycle.  An `Activity` may be exited by backing out of it, going on to a new `Activity`, or by the operating system terminating it in a low memory condition if you have taken it from the foreground.

In the low memory case, the entire application, including the `Application` class instance (and the beacon scanning service) is terminated along with the `Activity`.  This case is completely beyond your control, but the Android Beacon Library has code to automatically restart the application and the beacon scanning service a few minutes after this happens.

The tricky part for your purposes is to figure out in the `onCreate` method of the `Application` class whether this this is an app restart (after low memory shutdown), or a first time launch of the app before the `Activity` has ever been run.

A good way to do this is to store a timestamp in [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html) for when your `Activity` is launched.

So your `Application` class might have code like this:

```
public void onCreate() {
  ...
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  long lastActivityLaunchTime = prefs.getLong("myapp_activity_launch_time_millis", 0l);
  if (lastActivityLaunchTime > System.currentTimeMillis()-SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() ) {
    // If we are in here we have launched the Activity since boot, and this is a restart
    // after temporary low memory shutdown.  Need to start scanning
    startBeaconScanning();  
  }
}

public void startBeaconScanning() {
    Region region = new Region("backgroundRegion",
            null, null, null);
    mRegionBootstrap = new RegionBootstrap(this, region);
    mBackgroundPowerSaver = new BackgroundPowerSaver(this);      
}
```

In your `Activity` you will also need code to detect it is a first launch, and if so, start the scanning from there.

```
public void onCreate() {
  ...
  SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
  long lastActivityLaunchTime = prefs.getLong("myapp_activity_launch_time_millis", 0l);
  if (lastActivityLaunchTime < System.currentTimeMillis()-SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() ) {
    // This is the first Activity launch since boot
    ((MyApplication) this.getApplicationContext()).startBeaconScanning();
    SharedPreferences.Editor prefsEditor = prefs.edit();
    prefsEditor.putLong("myapp_activity_launch_time_millis", System.currentTimeMillis());
    prefsEditor.commit();
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow that's great news. So from what I have understood is that , I will make a `Application` class which will implement `BootStrapNotifier`  and in the `onCreate()` of `Application` class I will have to check whether the beacon detecting service was stopped(Because of low memory termination) and if it was stopped I would simply restart it. And in the `Activity`too  I would check whether the beacon detecting service was stopped and restart it.

Comment: Apart from that I don't have to override the `didEnterRegion()` in the `Application` class(Leaving it blank) and override the `didEnterRegion()` of the `Activity` only to do want I want to do when a beacon is detected(Which is the main logic that I want to execute only from the `Activity`)?